# Flash Drive does not show up

Tags: usb-drive

I'm not experienced with programming. I have been using Ubuntu Budgie for a few months. I used to be able to see a flash drive in my file manager, but after a recent update, it no longer appears. I have tried different flash drives. They light up, but none appear in the file manager. The usb port works for other purposes.